# C++ Requires expression for checking function signature does not work for Lambdas or member functions in gcc

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts

A c++20 requires expression can be used in order to check whether specific functions or types exist e.g. in a template argument and used in a concept.

In the code snipplet below I use a `requires` expression in order to check the signature of a function. 
I expected the `requires` expression to evaluate to `true` both for the lambda and for the defined function. 
The expression fails for the lambda expression though. 
**Why that is the case?**

```
int func(int a) noexcept { return 1; }

int main() {
  auto lam = [](int a) noexcept -> int { return 1; };
  // works fine for a function with this signature: 
  static_assert(requires(int a) {  { func(a) } ->std::same_as<int>;  });
  // the following three conditions each evaluate to false for the lambda
  static_assert(requires(int a) {
    lam(a);
    {lam(a)}->std::same_as<int>;
    requires std::is_same_v<decltype(lam(a)), int>;
  });
  return 0; 
}
```

The same applies for arbitrary member functions:

```
struct T { void f() noexcept; };

int main() {
  static_assert(requires(T o) {    o.f();  });
}
```

Compiled on gcc-10.0 and gcc-trunk, the code snipplet is available on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/VoNNfR).

Comment: gcc bug (although the nested `requires` expression you have is ill-formed)

Comment: Submitted [94252](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94252).

Comment: I didn't realize that. I also fixed the code snipplet in the question which evaluates to true (only the two previous expressions seem to be affected by the bug). Thanks for submitting the bug!

Comment: @Barry Why is the nested `requires` expression ill-formed?

Comment: @Oliv I was lacking the 'decltype(...)' in the first version of the question, I fixed that in my edit after reading Barry's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC that [is now fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94252) for the release of gcc 10.0.